# Create spine controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, coffeescript, spine.js

Im using spinejs, coffeescript and asp.net mvc.
Heres the code for spine controller class:

```
class Schedules extends Spine.Controller
    constructor: -> super alert "Created"

    events:
        "click": "click"

    click: ->
        alert("Was clicked")
```

In a asp.net mvc view I have all js included and the following code to init controller:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var sched = new Schedules({
         el: $("#myId")
     });  
});
```

But I see the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Schedules is not defined.

UPDATE:
Now I it doesn`t do anything and no error is provided. I cant see my alert message.
But it should show alert message after controller creation.
In controller file:

```
window.SchedulesApp = {}
class SchedulesApp.Schedules extends Spine.Controller
//futher controller code
```

In the asp.net mvc View I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var controller = new SchedulesApp.Schedules({});
```

Comment: Why downvote? I really can`t figure it out. Can you, please, help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using namespaces:

```
window.SchedulesApp = {}

class SchedulesApp.Schedules extends Spine.Controller
    constructor: ->
        super
        alert "Created"

    events:
        "click": "click"

    click: ->
        alert("Was clicked")
```

**EDIT**

So, you have another problem and that is how you call `super` which is causing everything afterwards to be wrapped into a parameter to `super`.

I have fixed it with the [CS output with jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianGenisio/dDaej/4/) and edited the CS in this answer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Brian, I used your way to define namespace and I do not get any errors. But alert that is in controller constructor was not executed. Actually nothing is executed and I can`t call methods of controller if I define them.

Comment: @YaroslavYakovlev can you create a jsFiddle to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/dDaej/ 
I tried to call controller.doStuff(and method was not defined). If reove this, no alerts still called on controller instantiation. The js I included was generated from coffeescript.

Comment: @YaroslavYakovlev Ha!  Take a look at the javascript in your fiddle.  You have a problem with the way you are calling super and it is passing everything else in as a parameter to super... not good!  :)  I edited my response and gave you a jsFiddle that works.

Comment: Brian, thanks a lot! Just started to learn both coffeescript and spine. Thanks for helping with this.